# GCP Snapshots export to Coldline to lower costs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I have a client who have long retention period and big snapshots created every day. I want to optimize their costs with allowing them to export older snapshots to more cost efficient storage. Can you help me to find what is the best practice for this use-case?

Comment: I think more suitable solution is to use Archive Snapshots - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots :

When you create a snapshot, you have the option of creating a standard snapshot or an archive snapshot. Archive snapshots have the same benefits as standard snapshots including incremental chains, compression, and encryption. However, archive snapshots are lower-cost and are better suited for use cases related to compliance, audit, and long-term cold storage.

Answer (score 1):

It was clearly documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#:%7E:text=Archive%20storage%20is%20the%20lowest,online%20backup%2C%20and%20disaster%20recovery.)

> Nearline storage is a low-cost, highly durable storage service for
> storing infrequently accessed data. Nearline storage is a better
> choice than Standard storage in scenarios where slightly lower
> availability, a 30-day minimum storage duration.
>
> Coldline storage is a very-low-cost, highly durable storage service
> for storing infrequently accessed data. Coldline storage is a better
> choice than Standard storage or Nearline storage in scenarios where
> slightly lower availability, a 90-day minimum storage duration.
>
> Archive storage is more cost-effective, as it offers the lowest
> storage costs,highly durable storage service for data archiving,
> online backup, and disaster recovery. Unlike the "coldest" storage
> services offered by other Cloud providers, your data is available
> within milliseconds, not hours or days,as well as a 365-day minimum
> storage duration.

You can choose which is best suited for your case with respect to cost and storage duration. You can also check GCP [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) to get an estimate of the cost for storing data in each storage class and region.